# Would the speed of a Cat6A with a 2-Pair Separator still be at 10GB/s

Tags: networking, ethernet, interference, cat6

[image: H-shaped Separator]

*Just some background*: I recently bought this discontinued product [Panduit Cat6A Ethernet Cable](https://www.panduit.com/en/products/copper-systems/bulk-copper-cable/enterprise-data-center-copper-cable/puc6xc04buceg.html) which is **CM-rated**. I was very confused if the separator is X-shaped or H-shaped, due to the fact that the sample photo of their product has X-shaped separator whilst [their Category6A Specification Sheet](https://www.panduit.com/content/dam/panduit/en/products/media/9/29/429/8429/68388429.pdf) shows it's H-shaped. So I went to ask the local online store what's the shape of the separator and told me it's X-shaped, so I ordered and it came. To my surprise it was actually what I feared, the H-shaped separator. I really hated it but don't have time to return and refund just for that case, so I would use the cable anyway since it's still a Category6A.

[image]

#### Would this Cat6A *actually* still be at 10GB/s though it uses 2-Pair(H-shaped) Separator? Wouldn't this be an issue concerning crosstalk and interference?

This is my worry. This cable is clearly labeled as Cat6A that should be able to run 10GB/s speed of data. Their [Category6A Specification Sheet](https://www.panduit.com/content/dam/panduit/en/products/media/9/29/429/8429/68388429.pdf) also states *Category 6A standards for swept frequencies up to 500 MHz*. If it causes crosstalk very frequently, it surely would resend more packets, and that makes 10GB/s unrealistic.

I can't find any article online about this kind of ethernet cable separator. I am hoping for a technical explanation or experience about this. I asked for the hope that it actually still does the job as a Category6A speed would, that is 10GB/s.

Comment: It is Cat-6A spec cable... what is your question? The H or X divider is just shown as a reference, as long as it meets/exceeds the specs, it fits the rating. Panduit is an extremely high quality manufacturer with a solid reputation, you will have no issues as long as you properly run and terminate in your cable.

Comment: Though it is a Cat6A am very skeptical due to the H-shaped Separator which I believe, is there to prevent Crosstalk and Interference between the pairs. I updated the question to highlight my question.

Comment: You have no logical reason to be skeptical, the cable does not have crosstalk issues... I have run hundreds of miles of Panduit Cat-6A cable as shown, terminated on Panduit TX6A modules and have certified all if it, never had a test fail to due the cable. Show me a failed test or some legitimate reason other than your skepticism and unwillingness to accept a reputable manufacturer's claims with no valid reason.

Comment: Sorry, I am skeptical because I am only self-taught on networking. I am very happy to hear someone's experience, is it the same H-shaped separator? I honestly can't find even a single article about those separators inside of an ethernet cable. This might be other topic but what's the real purpose of the Separator inside an ethernet cable?

Comment: If you are going to use it anyway, why don't just you try it out and measure the speed? Otherwise, I agree with @acejavelin: Cat-6A is Cat-6A, you can expect it to conform it to its specification. Case closed.

Comment: It does not use an H separator, in fact, across the 3 or 4 brands of 6A I've used, I've never seen an H separator, only X.

Comment: That's what I'm worried about, since it normally is an X shaped, but mine is H. I am following what you guys said for now to trust the specs of this Panduit Cat6A.